# Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. Killed by external signal

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm saving the output of a model as a table in google big query from dataproc cluster using the below code:

```
Rules.write \
      .format("bigquery") \
      .option("table","{}.{}".format(bq_dataset, bq_table)) \
      .option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket) \
      .mode('append') \
      .save()
```

Facing the below error while running the above code:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d844ab401d73> in <module>
     33       .option("table","{}.{}".format(bq_dataset, bq_table)) \
     34       .option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket) \
---> 35       .mode('append') \
     36       .save()
     37     #change overwrite to append

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    735             self.format(format)
    736         if path is None:
--> 737             self._jwrite.save()
    738         else:
    739             self._jwrite.save(path)

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o122.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to write to BigQuery
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:70)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:75)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 14, cluster-first-w-2.c.main, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1593684541132_0002_01_000005 on host: cluster-Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d844ab401d73> in <module>
     33       .option("table","{}.{}".format(bq_dataset, bq_table)) \
     34       .option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket) \
---> 35       .mode('append') \
     36       .save()
     37     #change overwrite to append

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    735             self.format(format)
    736         if path is None:
--> 737             self._jwrite.save()
    738         else:
    739             self._jwrite.save(path)

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o122.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to write to BigQuery
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:70)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:75)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 14, cluster-first-w-2.c.main.internal, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1593684541132_0002_01_000005 on host: cluster-first-w-2.c.main.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2020-07-02 12:16:23.881]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2020-07-02 12:16:23.881]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2020-07-02 12:16:23.882]Killed by external signal
.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1892)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1880)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2051)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 55 more. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2020-07-02 12:16:23.881]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2020-07-02 12:16:23.881]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2020-07-02 12:16:23.882]Killed by external signal
.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1892)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1880)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2051)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 55 more
```

Below is the log detail:

```
{
 insertId: "ukfr1kykqi44b6z0n"  
 jsonPayload: {
  application: "application_1593765937787_0003"   
  class: "org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator"   
  container: "container_1593765937787_0003_01_000001"   
  container_logname: "stderr"   
  filename: "application_1593765937787_0003.container_1593765937787_0003_01_000001.stderr"   
  message: "Container from a bad node: container_1593765937787_0003_01_000008 on host: cluster-first-w-2.c.main.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2020-07-03 10:47:32.493]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "4317452345300701444"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "cluster-first-w-1"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone: "us"   
 }
 logName: "projects/main/logs/yarn-userlogs"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-07-03T10:47:37.775061029Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name: "cluster-first"    
   cluster_uuid: "59505b2f-9814-4dbc-add1-9b93dabc7144"    
   project_id: "main"    
   region: "global"    
  }
  type: "cloud_dataproc_cluster"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 timestamp: "2020-07-03T10:47:32Z"  
}
```

According to my research online, the above error arises due to memory issue. I tried increasing the memory of my cluster and also tried increasing the memory overhead but still am unable to resolve this issue. What else can be done?

Comment: Found a similar issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29767

Comment: yea, i don't see a solution in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the container `container_1593684541132_0002_01_000005` was killed on request, you can search it in the YARN resource manager log `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager*.log` to figure out why it was killed.

Comment: I have included the log details in my question. Let me know if you can find anything that'll help us solve the problem .

Comment: That's yarn user log, not yarn resource manager log.

Comment: I'm new to this platform. Where can i find yarn resource manager log in dataproc cluster?

Comment: SSH into the master node, `cat /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager*.log`.

Comment: It is also available in Cloud Logs.